# Spring cloud gateway gives connection closed prematurely

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring cloud gateway as API gateway in my micro service setup with consul as service discovery.

In some case when API of some microservice take more then 2 minutes, gateway throws below error:

```
java.io.IOException: Connection closed prematurely
at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundClose(HttpClientOperations.java:269)
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelInactive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:420)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:377)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342)
at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:282)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:223)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1429)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:947)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:822)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:313)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried the same API multiple time, I got this error exactly after 2 minutes.

Is there any property settings.
Version and dependency details:

```
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign')


springBootVersion=2.0.3.RELEASE
springDMPVersion=1.0.4.RELEASE
springPlatformBomVersion=Cairo-SR2
```

Ribbon settings:

```
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 3000
  ReadTimeout: 3000
```

Comment: Could you please provide am example repo with those changes? I'd want to try it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Spring `RestTemplate` to send the requests?

Comment: Not sure, Gateway is responsible to forward the request to the application.Unaware about the underlying implementation

Comment: Yes, but I see you are using ribbon, which is a client-side load-balancer. So I assume you also control the client that makes the calls? What client is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue in downstream service.

In my application, there is nodejs application is running behind the spring cloud gateway and default time out is 2 min.

Ref: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3330

In my case after 2 min, nodejs application gives timeout and that is why I get an error in the gateway.

I resolved it by changing timeout values in node application

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered a similar problem. When spring gateway called other services, it reported the same error when uploading files. I try to add the following configuration to the yaml file of the called service. That's the solution. You can try it, too

spring:
servlet:
multipart:
max-file-size: 50MB
max-request-size: 50MB